# Jquery Each Get Attr

Tags: jquery, each, attr

I am trying to get the attribute of a an element that is inside an .each statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':not(select[name=""])').each(function(e) {
        var el = this.attr(name);
        alert('el');
    });
});
```

So if i had two elements that matched then I want it to alert twice.  Can someone help me fix my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: change `this.attr(name)` to this: `$(this).attr("name")`

Comment: and `alert('el');` to `alert(el);`

Comment: That did it.  Thanks... just my sloppy code I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to wrap the selector with $()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':not(select[name=""])').each(function(e) {
        var el = $(this).attr(name);
        alert(el); // also output the variable not a char
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `this` will refer to the DOMElement whereas to use the `attr()` method you need to get a jQuery object containing the element so you would need `$(this)`. Secondly, you would need to `alert(el)` without quotes. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':not(select[name=""])').each(function(e) {
        var el = $(this).attr(name);
        alert(el);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change `this.attr(name)` to `$(this).attr("name")` and (as Gary Storey said) `alert('el');` to `alert(el);`